# How to change fake laser scan direction of rotation

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, laser, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I've generated my fake laser scan from the Kinect sensor point cloud using laserscan_to_pointcloud and am doing 2D SLAM using gmapping in a manner similar to the Turtlebot, but it looks as if the occupancy grid is being updated as if the laser were rotating in the opposite direction (anticlockwise instead of clockwise).  What's the best way to change the laser scan direction within gmapping/slam_gmapping ?  Displaying the fake laser scan I can see that it's in the correct orientation, it's just the gmapping node which is mirroring it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9398/how-to-change-fake-laser-scan-direction-of-rotation/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Within the URDF the rpy orientation of the fake laser can be altered such that it's equivalent to turning it upside down.  This brings both the laser scan display and also the occupancy grid update into agreement.

---

Originally posted by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) with karma: 995 on 2011-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0